# how to start conference call programatically

Tags: android

I am creating an app depend on parent child relationship, in which when child got a call from a particular no, it should changed in a conference call with parent automatically.
Is it possible?

I read about a class `com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GSMPhone`
from which we can do this functionality. But I am not getting this class directly. So please help me to do this. I got the call from incoming call receiver.

Comment: did you read this question, how to make call conferencing of two calls?

Comment: Have you found any solution of this, Share your research here in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from an application. com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GSMPhone is an internal class and you cannot access it. You can try instantiate it by using JAVA reflection, but you will get exception. You can only set Phone state listener etc. from application or you can intercept the out going call by receiving some broadcast "NEW_OUTGOING_CALL".
try Like this, but it will not work :-)

```
try {
            final Class<?> classPhonefactory = classLoader
                    .loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory");
            Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory");

            // Object objPhonefactory = classPhonefactory.newInstance();



            Method method_getDefaultPhone;
            method_getDefaultPhone = classPhonefactory
                    .getDeclaredMethod("getGsmPhone");
            method_getDefaultPhone.setAccessible(true);
            Object phoneProxyInstance = method_getDefaultPhone.invoke(null, null);

            if (null == phoneProxyInstance) {
                Log.i("CALLActivity", "Exception!");
            } else {
                Log.i("CALLActivity", "GOT phoneProxyInstance!");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("CALLActivity", "PhoneFactory", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```